# Nested convex hulls in Hadamard manifold

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, non-positive-curvature

Let $F$ be a finite set in a [Hadamard manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_manifold) $H$, and $W\supset F$ is its neighborhood.

> Is it true that the closure of the convex hull of $F$ lies in the interior of the convex hull of $W$?

**Comments.**

- If $\dim H=2$, then the answer is yes.
- I can show that $\partial \mathrm{Conv}\, F\cap \partial \mathrm{Conv}\, W$ cannot have isolated points.
- An analogous statement for CAT(0) metrics on the plane does not hold.
- This question is motivated by the last lines in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277510/existence-of-barycenter)

Comment: Is it easy to describe the CAT(0) metrics on the plane that provide counterexamples to this?

Comment: @AndyPutman take flat plane with one singular point $p$ with total angle $>2\cdot\pi$ arount it. If  $p\in\partial(\mathrm{Conv}\,F)$, then likely $p\in\partial(\mathrm{Conv}\,W)$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!